# Where does the history for getHistoryForKey came from?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When a Hyperledger Fabric smart contract calls [getHistoryForKey](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-node/release-2.2/api/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html#getHistoryForKey__anchor) it receive the updates for a particular key. I'm wondering where does this information come from? It's not stored in the world-view (levelDB, CouchDB) so it must be retrieved from the blockchain. Does the smart contract has access to blockchain? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [setting](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-2.2/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L681) which enables the history database for peers.  It is enabled by default and is a a physically separate database from world state.

Each channel has it's own history database.  The history database uses LevelDB (an embedded database) for storage.

The history database stores key/txid/blocknum for each update. When you call GetHistoryForKey, it iterates through the history db and then retrieves the values from block storage.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate a bit more? What kind of database is it? Can I access it another way than getHistoryForKey API? What are the limits?

Comment: Added additional detail to the answer as well.  The history database uses an embedded database (LevelDB) for storage.  If your peer is not running and/or you copy the database file, you can access the history db using your own LevelDB application, but other than that there is not way to directly access it.

Comment: Does it mean that each update is stored twice ? In history database and as transaction in blockchain history archive?

Comment: It just stores a history of all the transactions which modified the key.  It does not actually store the values.

Comment: Right, my question is if there is a third kind of storage (besides world-view and blockchain https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/ledger/ledger.html) used to store these updates? Does the getHistoryForKey query the blockchain to get a history of a transaction or some different storage (not included in the definition in the link) that stores these updates (therefore storing them twice: 1) in the blockchain, 2) in the updates levelDB database)?

Comment: The history db stores key/txid/blockno for each update.  When you call GetHistoryForKey, it iterates through the history db and then retrieves the values from block storage.  So values are not saved in a 3rd location.

Comment: As we are storing only blockno. It should iterate the blocks  to go that particular block and fetch the transaction? So  if there are 1 lakh blocks and block no is 50k it shoudl iterate 50k blocks to get that transction. Am i right?